# Not able to resolve 127.0.0.1 to custom domain

Tags: iis, localhost, hosts

In Hosts file under system32/drivers/etc  I am doing this

```
 # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
 #  127.0.0.1       localhost
 #  ::1             localhost
 127.0.0.1 debugmodesample.com
```

but some how 127.0.0.1 is not resolving to debugmodesample.com

Ping is not working with debugmodesample.com

Comment: Just add www before the debugmodesample.com. it will work. i.e. www.debugmodesample.com

Comment: Are you sure that you have mapped this domain in IIS in Website bindings also ? Coz otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, working fine here, I suspect if IIS is running and up on port 80... no idea otherwise !

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to bind domain name in IIS?

```
Open IIS Manager. (Assuming IIS 7).

In the Connections pane, expand the Sites node in the tree, and then click to select the site for which you want to add a binding.

In the Actions pane, click Bindings.

In the Site Bindings dialog box, click Add.

In the Add Site Binding dialog box, add the binding information and then click OK.
```

In binding information, enter proper host name then check it in the browser.